# Kubernetes - Unknown admission plugin: DefaultStorageClass

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Kubernetes API server is not getting started due to DefaultStorageClass.

**The connection to the server 10.85.40.165:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
(kubectl failed, will retry 2 times)**

Ubuntu: 14.04.4

**kubectl version**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"5cb86ee022267586db386f62781338b0483733b3", GitTreeState:"clean"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"5cb86ee022267586db386f62781338b0483733b3", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

**Docker info**

```
docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.10.3
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 0
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 4.2.0-27-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.67 GiB
Name: stage-kube01
ID: 45T4:TF3N:VK4V:ELG3:NZA2:V5KJ:N6WE:W5RD:5F2Q:RRIZ:ZZJ4:TBZP
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

---

**Kube-apiserver.log**

```
  mv: extensions/__internal 
I0922 17:30:27.725853    9012 genericapiserver.go:82] Adding storage destination for group batch

F0922 17:30:28.418600    9012 plugins.go:107] Unknown admission plugin: DefaultStorageClass 

I0922 17:30:28.455859    9025 server.go:188] Will report 10.85.40.165 as public IP address.

I0922 17:30:28.455983    9025 plugins.go:71] No cloud provider specified.

I0922 17:30:28.456165    9025 server.go:112] constructing etcd storage interface.   sv: v1   mv: __internal

I0922 17:30:28.456335    9025 genericapiserver.go:82] Adding storage destination for group

I0922 17:30:28.456382    9025 server.go:296] Configuring extensions/v1beta1 storage destination

I0922 17:30:28.456411    9025 server.go:112] constructing etcd storage interface.   sv: extensions/v1beta1
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.

I removed "DefaultStorageClass" from the ADMISSION_CONTROL variable in ubuntu/config-default.sh, and I was able to start my cluster. However, I haven't fully tested everything out to make sure it's all still working.

Comment: I had the same issue. Solved it as suggested. Kube-down is waiting forever for pods to go down. Not sure if this is the reason

Comment: @Tchinmai You will need to delete all resources from kube-system if any.